# Lamp API not showing up?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceGd4.jpg)I have been trying to create a flashlight app using Lamp API.
But I cant seem to find the Windows.Devices.Lights namespace. Is that a dll error ? I have been using VS2015 Community. I have inspected my object browser and other namespaces of similar prefix(Windows.Devices.xyz) are available.

Thanks !

Comment: You want to create a Universal app, not a Phone 8.1 app. The Lamp API is part of the Universal App Platform; it is not available in the Phone SDK.

Comment: That worked ! Thanks !

Comment: In contrast to what Raymond said, it is possible. You need to use the torchlight as told in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the light on the phone you should look at the torch control in Window Phone 8.1

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.torchcontrol.aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you create the project, select Universal app, not Phone 8.1. The Lamp API is part of the Universal App Platform; it is not available in the Phone SDK.

Comment: It is in the windows Phone SDK, check the link of Tom Droste

Comment: @SynerCoder Lamp is in the Universal SDK. TorchControl is in the Phone SDK. If you want to use Lamp, then you need to be Universal.

Comment: Lamp... Torch... Poteto, Potato. Same difference. His question is clear that he wants to use the LED of his phone. The torch api does that.